# Using sed to find lines with specific keywords

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

This is in bash using CentOS

I am attempting to use `sed` to scan a text file to find lines that contain both the phrases "`define`" and "`REV_NUMBER`" (what lies before, in between, and after doesn't matter). However, I also want to ignore lines that have "`//`" in them because these indicate comments (the source file is a Verilog file).

My code is as follows:

```
REV=$(SED -n '/define REV_NUMBER/p' text.vh <<< $REV)
RESULT=$(echo "$REV")
```

This covers all lines that include:

```
define REV_NUMBER
```

But I want it to include lines that have, say:

```
define              REV_NUMBER
```

Or any number of whitespace between the words.
But ignore lines that have

```
//define REV_NUMBER
//define      REV_NUMBER
//    define REV_NUMBER
```

I stumped how to achieve this. New to bash/shell scripting and sed. Normally a C++ guy using strings.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `sed` command:

```
sed -n '/define  *REV_NUMBER/{\~^ *//~!p;}' file
define              REV_NUMBER
```

Comment: is there anyway to disregard tab as well?

Comment: Yes unread of above command use `sed -n '/define[[:blank:]]\+REV_NUMBER/{\~^[[:blank:]]*//~!p;}' file`

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't three `grep` connected by pipe be more readable?

```
grep -v "//" $FILE | grep "define" | grep "REV_NUMBER"
```